# VueJS: How to set model of an input without having it to be on the input

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want an input to have no value on it's element on the view side but underneath I want it to have a default value, here is some snippet to explain my point:

```
          <input
            class="form-control"
            v-model="amount"
            type="number"
            step=".01"
            min="0"
            required>
          </input>
```

I want amount to be 0 by default but not render 0 on the input, is this possible in vuejs? If the `input[type="number"] = ''`, the value of the property is 0 and not ' '.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a computed property with getter and setter. The getter can return an empty string if the value is zero...

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'main',
  data: {
    amount: 0
  },
  computed: {
    formattedAmount: {
      get () {
        return this.amount || ''
      },
      set (value) {
        this.amount = parseFloat(value) || 0
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <input class="form-control" v-model="formattedAmount" type="number" step=".01" min="0" placeholder="Amount" required/>
  <pre>amount = {{ amount }}</pre>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the model values

```js
var myObject = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    amount: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <input class="form-control" v-model="amount" type="number" step=".01" min="0" required>
    </input>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer but my question means that I have `this.amount = 0` but not render 0 on the number box itself but instead it displays as an empty number box. Is this possible?

Comment: ughhh.. What I mean is that on the 'users perspective' when he looks at the input it is empty.. but underneath, it has a value of 0. Hopefully this is clearer